# Garmin inReach vs. overcast sky

Tags: navigation, communication, satellite-phones

Garmin says about inReach that to have a two-way satellite communication *"you need to have a clear view of the sky".*

And what about cloud cover?.. Say it's winter and 100% overcast with angry cumulus clouds 100% of the time. How much interference / hindrance would that give?

**NOTE** Maybe not everyone knows what's an [inReach](https://buy.garmin.com/en-GB/GB/p/561286) is. It is **NOT** a GPS navigational device per se, it is a two-way satellite communicator that uses the [Iridium network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iridium_satellite_constellation).

Comment: None: please see this answer on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15334806/4142924).

Comment: Thanks @WeatherVane. However, passively receiving a GPS signal (from a powerful satellite) and actively communicating with the Iridium network (from a low-power handheld device) are not exactly the same use cases :)

Comment: Please add that clarification into the question.

Comment: Yep, already done :)

Comment: [In-Depth Garmin Inreach Explorer Review](https://hikingguy.com/hiking-gear/in-depth-garmin-inreach-explorer-review/) says *The antenna does best when it has a clear line-of-sight to the sky, but I’ve used it in a canopy of trees without problems.  Other times cloud cover has made a connection tough. I think it’s more a function of satellite technology rather than the unit itself.*

Comment: It would depend upon how much moisture is in the clouds and how thick they are. It is similar to your satellite TV receiver having poorer reception during storms. However, it would not be affected as much as TV because it is not sending a continuous stream of data (versus your tiny message) and it can afford to wait a while before each retry. I don't recall if it said what its timeout was but I know it will attempt for at least a couple minutes.

Comment: @Alexander `passively receiving a GPS signal (from a powerful satellite)` That's somewhat false as the GNSS signals are relatively weak. The satellites transmit at about 50W.

Comment: When they say "clear view of the sky," they just mean that you're not indoors, not in a deep canyon, not between skyscrapers in the middle of Manhattan, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Iridium uses radio frequencies [around 1.6 GHz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L_band#Telecommunications_use) or 18.75cm wavelength.

[Atmospheric absorption](http://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/atm-absorption.htm) at these frequencies is very low:

[image]

Clouds contain water droplets, though. So, let's have a look at [rain attenuation](http://wtlab.iis.u-tokyo.ac.jp/wataru/lecture/rsgis/rsnote/cp3/cp3-2.htm):

[image]

...no problem either at 1.6GHz. So your answer is: **overcast weather should be absolutely fine**. The designers wouldn't have picked a frequency that would be heavily absorbed by clouds... that would be bad for business.

Now, what happens at the bottom of a narrow canyon (or in a street with tall buildings)?...

[image]

Radio waves bend around corners due to diffraction. However... unlike a car, [diffraction](https://www.ck12.org/book/CK-12-Physical-Science-For-Middle-School/section/19.3/) works best on sharp corners, or obstacles which have at least one dimension that is close to, or smaller than the wavelength (here, 16cm). So, if there is a telephone pole between you and the satellite, waves will go around it. But if it is a building, they won't. You'll get rather low diffraction around large natural obstacles, which in practice means if you're at the bottom of a narrow canyon or street and the satellite is hidden behind the canyon walls, or behind a building, without direct sight, then reception won't work.

Likewise, Charlie mentions a reflective tarp, if that's conductive it will reflect the signal, so if you stand below it, it won't work. Roughly speaking, anything conductive either solid or with holes smaller than the wavelength will block/reflect the signal (for example, wire fence, rebar, steel roof, metal window blinds, etc). If it is between you and the satellite, expect problems.

Comment: This is the perfect answer, from the theoretical and practical standpoints.

Comment: @GabrielC.Thanks!

Comment: That is indeed a perfect answer peufeu, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

I have an inReach and have used it in all sorts of conditions and terrain. Overcast weather is not a problem but a reflective tarp or deep canyons can be.

If a message fails to get through the device will flash red and that means you need a better position.

Normally it’s not a problem.

Comment: The aluminium in a reflective tarp completely blocks radio waves, to the point where you could use it as a ground plane for an antenna. Aluminium foil is often used to [shield GNSS antennas from the rest of the electronics on drones](https://community.emlid.com/uploads/default/original/2X/c/ccdc77af330d3a8c168c079f43dea91e8bcd4206.jpg).

Answer (score -1):

I just purchased an inReach mini. In doing testing, the log tracking is not good. I just walked 1.4 miles according to map my walk on my phone which accurately tracked the route. It was cloudy and the inReach would not send a message and tracked only .4 miles of the walk.

I'm not sure I can trust this device to save me with its SOS feature if it will only work in clear skys.

Comment: Welcome to TGO. Kindly [edit](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/posts/24882/edit)  the punctuation and style so we can all understand what you're saying. Maybe "mi" for miles?

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for sharing your experience. However, inaccuracy of tracking is related to GPS signal, not two-way Iridium communication. You also mention that "it wouldn't send a message", that's more serious... but have you used it according to the Garmin's suggestions (making sure the antenna is out there, making sure there're no canyons / leaves etc.)? I've been heavily using inReach for two years now and have run into very few issues!

Answer (score -1):

I am an inReach user. I've run into problems getting a signal on cloudy days in the mountains of Colorado. Granted I was in forested mountains and it was cloudy. But I did nonetheless run into situations where I wasn't able to communicate. I do like the little thing but I don't think its 100% foolproof in all situations.